# How to use jetpack compose paging with LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I am trying to display paged items using LazyVerticalGrid. The code I am trying is shown below.

```
 val categories = repo.categories.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

 LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
 ) {

      items(categories) { category ->
          Box(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
              CategoryView(category)
          }
      }

 }
```

Please note that I have imported `androidx.paging.compose.items` and `androidx.paging.compose.collectAsLazyPagingItems`. Also `categories` is of type `LazyPagingItems<Category>`.

It works perfectly with `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow` but not `LazyVerticalGrid`.
The error I am getting is:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Int
Found:
LazyPagingItems<Category>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I came up with a solution by writing an extension function for `LazyGridScope` like the one written for `LazyListScope` in the `androidx.paging:paging-compose` library.

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
public fun <T: Any> LazyGridScope.items(
    lazyPagingItems: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(value: T?) -> Unit
) {
    items(lazyPagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
        itemContent(lazyPagingItems[index])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wonder how LazyColumn worded for you.  For me it complains the stuff on requiring Int.  So I have to provide the same extension function for LazyListScope

Comment: @LeoXJ you dont. You have the wrong import for it. There are multiple items() functions

Answer (score 9):

For me the accepted answer didn't work.
Instead of adding extension function I used the following way

```
val res = viewModel.getFeedResultStream().collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)){
    items(res.itemCount)
    { index ->
        res[index]?.let {
            FeedItem(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

copied from androidx.paging:paging-compose

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> LazyGridScope.items(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyGridItemScope.(item: T?) -> Unit
) {
    items(
        count = items.itemCount,
        key = if (key == null) null else { index ->
            val item = items.peek(index)
            if (item == null) {
                PagingPlaceholderKey(index)
            } else {
                key(item)
            }
        }
    ) { index ->
        itemContent(items[index])
    }
}

@SuppressLint("BanParcelableUsage")
private data class PagingPlaceholderKey(private val index: Int) : Parcelable {
    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(index)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object {
        @Suppress("unused")
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<PagingPlaceholderKey> =
            object : Parcelable.Creator<PagingPlaceholderKey> {
                override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) =
                    PagingPlaceholderKey(parcel.readInt())

                override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<PagingPlaceholderKey?>(size)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer is outdated. This is working great with androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha15

Comment: this answer is the real answer

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create a extension function. Just use the other version of `items` function.

```
val categories = repo.categories.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

 LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
 ) {
      items(
        categories.itemCount
      ) { index ->
          Box(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
              CategoryView(categories[index])
          }
      }

 }
```